How can I fix numpy not importing correctly when trying to import it from a non locally-available place?
I am trying to use numpy on the felk version of the dolphin emulator, and when importing it, it breaks. I am using sys to import the folder in which numpy is located as well.
Here is the code I am using to import numpy:
sys.path.append(f"c:\\users\\USER\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python312\\lib\\site-packages")
sys.path.append(f"c:\\users\\USER\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python310\\lib\\site-packages")
import numpy

Here is the Error I receive in the dolphin debug view:
09:09:157 Scripting\ScriptingEngine.cpp:17 I[Scripting]: Initializing scripting engine...
09:09:160 Scripting\Python\PyScriptingBackend.cpp:65 I[Scripting]: Initializing embedded python... 3.12.0 (tags/v3.12.0:0fb18b0, Oct  2 2023, 12:50:37) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)]
09:09:382 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
09:09:382 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
09:09:383 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:     from . import multiarray
09:09:383 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
09:09:384 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:     from . import overrides
09:09:384 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 8, in <module>
09:09:384 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:     from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
09:09:384 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
09:09:384 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
09:09:384 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
09:09:384 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 144, in <module>
09:09:385 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:     from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
09:09:385 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\numpy\__config__.py", line 4, in <module>
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:     from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:     raise ImportError(msg)
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: ImportError: 
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: installed.
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:     https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: Please note and check the following:
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   * The Python version is: Python3.12 from "C:\Users\USER\Downloads\Modded_dolphin_2\dolphin\Binary\x64\DolphinD.exe"
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   * The NumPy version is: "1.26.4"
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
09:09:386 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
09:09:387 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "C:/Users/USER/Downloads/Modded_Dolphin_maybe_work/dolphin/Binary/x64/Scripts for dolphin - PAL/Get speed but in other file 3.py", line 10, in <module>
09:09:387 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:     import numpy
09:09:387 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 149, in <module>
09:09:387 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:     raise ImportError(msg) from e
09:09:387 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
09:09:387 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:         its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
09:09:387 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:         your python interpreter from there.

I have also tried the suggested thing of uninstalling and reinstalling the correct version of numpy, but it still doesn't work.
I have used pip to install it, and importing it into python 3.10 and 3.12 on their own, and it works fine. The issue only seems to arise when I try to import it whilst also using the emulator.
I have also used the commandline option --no-python-subinterpreters as was suggested on the github(https://github.com/Felk/dolphin)
Edit: I have been doing some debugging, trying to figure  out what is happening, and used sys.path in my normal python environment, and then used sys.path.append("MY_PATHS")(for all of them) and run it in dolphin, and the output I got was still the same.
If I try to pip install directly to the python 312 folder that dolphin is using, then it just opens the folder, but doesn't install anything.
The python312 folder that dolphin is using is a zipped folder, but when I unzip it, it no longer works. Could this be the issue, and if so how do I unzip it without it breaking?
This is the error when I unzip the folder, and remove the zipped version:
44:51:051 Scripting\Python\Modules\controllermodule.cpp:838 E[Scripting]: Failed to load embedded python code into controller module
44:51:051 Scripting\Python\Modules\dolphinmodule.cpp:44 E[Scripting]: Failed to load embedded python code into dolphin module
44:51:051 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1316, in _find_and_load_unlocked
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1256, in _find_spec
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1524, in find_spec
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1498, in _get_spec
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<frozen zipimport>", line 111, in find_spec
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 675, in spec_from_loader
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 821, in spec_from_file_location
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<frozen zipimport>", line 170, in get_filename
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<frozen zipimport>", line 700, in _get_module_code
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<frozen zipimport>", line 534, in _get_data
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\USER\\Downloads\\Modded_Dolphin_maybe_work\\dolphin\\Binary\\x64\\python-embed\\python312.zip'
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: SystemError: execution of module dolphin_controller raised unreported exception
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "C:/Users/USER/Downloads/Modded_Dolphin_maybe_work/dolphin/Binary/x64/Scripts for dolphin - PAL/Get speed but in other file 3.py", line 1, in <module>
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:     from dolphin import event, gui, memory, registers
44:51:052 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: SystemError: execution of module dolphin raised unreported exception

Here's the error when I have both the zipped and unzipped folder in place:
49:12:655 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
49:12:655 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "C:/Users/USER/Downloads/Modded_Dolphin_maybe_work/dolphin/Binary/x64/Scripts for dolphin - PAL/Get speed but in other file 3.py", line 36, in <module>
49:12:655 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:     import numpy
49:12:655 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<frozen zipimport>", line 137, in get_code
49:12:655 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<frozen zipimport>", line 700, in _get_module_code
49:12:655 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr:   File "<frozen zipimport>", line 546, in _get_data
49:12:656 Scripting\Python\Modules\doliomodule.cpp:36 E[Scripting]: Script stderr: zipimport.ZipImportError: bad local file header: 'C:\\Users\\USER\\Downloads\\Modded_Dolphin_maybe_work\\dolphin\\Binary\\x64\\python-embed\\python312.zip'


Looks like a dependency problem (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'), there are some support libraries with numpy and if you only import the numpy folder it fails usually. Maybe check https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html for more details on this kind of errors.

@Aldehyde I have looked at the suggested webpage, and tried checking the path, then added all my site packages from python 3.10, including ones that aren't numpy, but it still isn't working. Importing numpy works fine in a default python 3.10 environment, and a python 3.11 environment, but only breaks when I try to import it into the dolphin emulator.
